# Stripe connect API saying balance is -1, while dashboard says it's 0?

Tags: go, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the balance of a Stripe connect account with the following code:
[image]

I added some detailed logging since the balance returned is different than what is on my dashboard. When this code runs, it says the account has $-1.00 in value. The thing is, this is for a brand new account. The dashboard interface shows the following:

[image]

For the API response, it shows this output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here, and why is the balance appearing differently via the API than what's displayed on the dash?

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot the problem here as we can't access your Stripe account. I'd suggest you to contact Stripe support and they can help you with account-related questions https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: If it helps, this is the same for every new account created. They all report $-1.00